# SQL : Replace text value in a column using old-new values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace, query-optimization

I have a `table A` that contains a text column.
In my stored proc I have a temp table containing two columns- old value and new value, having a number of rows.
 I need to replace all the occurrences of old values with the new values specified in the temp table, in the text column in my `table A`.

The text field in table A is not the same as the oldvalue in temp table so I can't use a join. The text column value could be 'there is nothing there'. There could be a row in temp table with oldvalue='there' and newvalue='here'.
Finally, the column value should be replaced by 'here is nothing here'. This should be applied to all rows of the column in `table A`.

One option is to iterate through the temp table(not preferable). Is there a better/elegant/optimized way to do it?

Comment: Example data might help. Do you mean that the temp table contains for example `(old,new)(dog,wolf),(brown,black)` and you want to update the string "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" to "the quick black wolf jumped over the lazy dog"?

Comment: @MartinSmith - Exactly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace part of string with capitalised equivalent from cross ref temp table - tsql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918473/replace-part-of-string-with-capitalised-equivalent-from-cross-ref-temp-table-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
;with r as (
  select 
    row_number() over(order by oldv) rn
    ,oldv
    ,newv
  from #replacevalues
)
,
res as (
  select 
    0 as ver
    ,txt as oldcte
    ,txt as newcte
  from tablea
  union all
  select 
    ver+1
    ,oldcte
    ,replace(newcte,oldv,newv)
  from res 
  join r 
    on r.rn=ver+1
)
update t
  set txt = res.newcte
from tablea t
join res on t.txt = res.oldcte
where res.ver = (select max(ver) from res)
```

Comment: The text field in table A is not the same as the oldvalue in temp table so I can't use a join. The text column value could be 'there is nothing there'. There could be a row in temp table with oldvalue='there' and newvalue='here'. Now, the output should be 'here is nothing here'. This should be applied to all rows of the column in table A. Hope I am making sense. :)

Comment: Try to show some example data .. cause I do not understand. This will put the new value where it will match an old value in table a

Comment: Edited my comment with an example.